# How can I have 2 users logged in at the same time in a Laravel App

Tags: database, laravel, authentication, architecture

Please help me architect the following case in Laravel:

Every instance of the Laravel app (ex. a company) will have a single username (super-user) who can control the sub-users. The super-user will log into the app once to allow the sub-users to log in and out many times throughout the day. The sub-users won't be able to access the app at all without the super-user logging in.

Example: A POS system that the manager logs into once a day. It doesn't log itself out all throughout the day. The cashiers simply tap in their password to gain access and it auto-logs out after 5 mins. There's a single system in the store so the cashiers have to keep switching on and off. The cashier wont be able to use the POS at all if the manager does not log in.

Im new to Laravel. I know I need multiple guards but how do I access auth so that it doesn't keep directing me to the super-user? Im thinking of using the default laravel authentication for the superuser. But what about the other users?

Any help or pointers in the right direction is highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel cannot persist multiple authenticated users at once but you don't necessarily need that for this system, in fact you may be able to design a more robust system without it.

Defining the problem (rather than a solution) we'd say something like, "The system must allow for a manager to enable and disable the POS for cashiers so that they are only able to access it when authorised".

A system that achieves that goal can be built with a single Laravel authentication system, using different roles (`manager`, `cashier`) and the associated permissions. This is (fortunately) very straightforward with Laravel.

The user flow would be along the lines of:

1. A cashier visits the POS terminal
2. The cashier clicks "log in"
3. The cashier enters their identifying details
4. The system finds the user, identifies that they're a cashier, then checks if cashiers are allowed to log in

   - If yes, the cashier is logged in and able to access the POS functionality
   - If no, the cashier log in is rejected with an error

The manager flow would be along the lines of:

1. A manager visits the POS terminal
2. The manager clicks "log in"
3. The manager enters their identifying details
4. The system accepts their log in and sends them to the management dashboard

The management dashboard would be where the manager could control other users (create and manage cashiers (edit, delete, audit)) and set the system status as activated for cashiers, this would be protected with [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-policies).

At the start of business the manager would log in to the POS and activate it for cashiers by setting the "active" flag to true, then the manager would log out. Through the day any cashier could log in and use it. At the end of the day the manager would log in and deactivate the POS for cashiers.

An added benefit of this system is that you could allow managers to *also* be cashiers so if they needed to use the POS during the day they would not need a separate account. A users manager status could be a simple `is_manager` database column. You could additionally implement programmatic scheduled POS availability, i.e: "allow log in from cashiers between 9am and 5pm".

Laravel is a great choice for this project as it provides everything you need out of the box, let me know if you have any other questions about your implementation :-)